# How to setup connection (choosing ip adress) from Android App on physical device to Python Program using sockets?

Tags: python, java, android-studio, sockets, networking

I am a beginner in socket programming. I wrote a Python code that creates a socket listening on port 12345 :

```
port=12343
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
IP = '0.0.0.0'
s.bind((IP,port))
s.listen(nb_max_connex)

print(f"Le serveur est lancé sur {IP} sur le port {port}.")

connexion,addresse=s.accept() #accepter la connexion 
print("Connecté à ",addresse)
```

Here is my java code :

```
            Socket soc=new Socket("10.0.2.2",12343);
            if(soc.isConnected()){
                CharSequence text = "La connexion avec le système a été réalisée";
                Context context = GlobalApplication.getAppContext();
                Log.d("CONNECT","connecté au socket");
                //Toast.makeText(context,text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

10.0.2.2 works well with android emulator, the connection is successful. However when I install my app on my phone, I can't determine how the connection can be made, I have tried using  Socket soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1",12343) but there is no connection...

Could someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, to work, you need your laptop and mobile to connect to the same network. Then get your laptop's local IP address like below.

**How to get your IP address:**

**On windows**
Open command prompt-> type ipconfig --> copy you device IP
read this for more https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/find-your-ip-address-in-windows-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9

**On Linux and Mac**
open terminal -> type ifconfig --> copy you device ip
read this for more [https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/ip-address-3676112/#:~:text=the%20search%20bar.-,How%20to%20find%20your%20local%20internal%20(private/local)%20IP%20address,-The%20IP%20address](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/ip-address-3676112/#:%7E:text=the%20search%20bar.-,How%20to%20find%20your%20local%20internal%20(private/local)%20IP%20address,-The%20IP%20address)

```
Socket soc=new Socket("laptop-ip-address",12343);
            if(soc.isConnected()){
                CharSequence text = "La connexion avec le système a été réalisée";
                Context context = GlobalApplication.getAppContext();
                Log.d("CONNECT","connecté au socket");
                //Toast.makeText(context,text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: It finally worked using the ip you have suggested + making wifi hotspot from my laptop (where my python program is running) and connecting to this hotspot from my android physical device (where i installed my app). thanks for your suggestions :)